# Codeigniter mail Internal server error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, internal-server-error

When trying to send an email with either sendmail or smtp I get an Internal Server Error.
I receive the email but something goes wrong with cookies according to the error log:

> mod_security: Access denied with code 500. Error parsing cookies: Error normalising cookie value: Invalid character detected [0] [hostname "myDomain.be"] [uri "/favicon.ico"]

I don't know what the favicon.ico is doing there, because I don't user a favicon

```
$this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('name'));
            $this->email->to('xxx@xxx.com'); 

            $this->email->subject('xxxcontact');
            $this->email->message($this->input->post('message'));   
            $this->email->set_alt_message($this->input->post('message'));
            ($this->email->send())
```

I have my configuration defined in a config file.

Comment: Seems to me its more related to something that happens after you send the email, maybe a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my ignorance but why `$this->email->send()` is in brackets? Try to see the output with `<?php echo $this->email->print_debugger(); ?>`